# Filtered Dropdown value from Google Script

Tags: javascript, json, forms, google-apps-script

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364042/create-dropdown-from-json-data-on-html-page-using-google-apps-script), I would like to change the data in an HTML dropdown when the user select a dropdown option.
Here, I want to filter the data depending on wichh field the user has selected. The difference is that the filtered is in a GS file.

EDIT: In two words, I would like to do the same that the post before but with two parameters

Here's my code.

**Google script**

```
// uniqueContractScopeData, uniqueAcTypeData and uniqueCustomerData are tables of Strings.
They send the expected data.

function get_joCustomer() {
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i < uniqueCustomerData.length; i++ ) {
    var record = {};
    record['customer'] = uniqueCustomerData[i];
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
  jo.user = dataArray;
  return JSON.stringify(jo);
}

function get_joContractScope() {
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  for( var i=0; i < uniqueContractScopeData.length; i++ ) {
    var record = {};
    record['contractScope'] = uniqueContractScopeData[i];
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
  jo.user = dataArray;
  return JSON.stringify(jo);
}

function get_joAcType() {
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  for( var i=0; i < uniqueAcTypeData.length; i++ ) {
    var record = {};
    record['acType'] = uniqueAcTypeData[i];
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
  jo.user = dataArray;
  return JSON.stringify(jo);
}

// Work
function processGet_jo(element, returnedAssociatedData) {
  var uniqueData = getUniqueAssociatedElement(element, returnedAssociatedData); // Returns expected result which is a table of Strings
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  var result;
  for (var i=0; i < uniqueData.length; i++ ) {
    var record = {};
    record[returnedAssociatedData] = uniqueData[i];
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
  jo.user = dataArray;
  return JSON.stringify(jo);
}
```

**.html**

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <!-- form -->
        <form id="filterForm" onChange="displayAppropriatedValues(this)" onSubmit="handleFormSubmitFilter(this)">
    
        <label for="customer"> Customer </label><br/>
        <select id="customer" name="customer">
          <option selected></option><br/>
        </select><br/><br/>
    
          <label for="contractScope"> Contract Scope </label><br/>
          <select name="contractScope" id="contractScope">
            <option selected></option><br/>
          </select><br/><br/>
         
          <label for="acType"> AC Type </label><br/>
          <select multiple id="acType" name="acType">
            <option></option><br/>
          </select><br/><br/>
    
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
    
        <script>


//When the form is opened, dropdown options are generated. No problems here
    
    var customerHtml = document.getElementById("customer");
    var customerHtmlValue = customerHtml.options[customerHtml.selectedIndex].value;
    var contractScopeHtml = document.getElementById("contractScope");
    var contractScopeHtmlValue = contractScopeHtml.options[contractScopeHtml.selectedIndex].value;
    var acTypeHtml = document.getElementById("acType");
    var acTypeHtmlValue = contractScopeHtml.options[contractScopeHtml.selectedIndex].value;
    
            (function () {
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
                function(value) {
                  var jo = JSON.parse(value);             
                  for(var i=0; i < jo.user.length-1; i++) {
                    var user = jo.user[i];
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = user.customer;
                    option.value = option.text;
                    customerHtml.add(option);
                  }
                }
              ).get_joCustomer();
    
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
                function(value) {
                  var jo = JSON.parse(value);
                  for( var i=0; i < jo.user.length-1; i++ ) {
                    var user = jo.user[i];
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = user.contractScope;
                    option.value = option.text;
                    contractScopeHtml.add(option);
                  }
                }
              ).get_joContractScope();
    
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
                function(value) {
                  var jo = JSON.parse(value);
                  for( var i=0; i < jo.user.length-1; i++ ) {
                    var user = jo.user[i];
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = user.acType;
                    option.value = option.text;
                    acTypeHtml.add(option);
                  }
                }
              ).get_joAcType();
            }());
  
  
          function displayAppropriatedValues(form) {
    
            if (customer.value == "A") {
    
              // Delete all options
              var L = contractScopeHtml.options.length;
              for(var i = L; i >= 1; i--) {
                  contractScopeHtml.remove(i);
              } // Work


    //The problem is here. The customerHtmlValue and returnedAssociatedData parameters are not recognised at the end of the function.
        (function () {
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
                function(value) {
                  var jo = JSON.parse(value);
                  for( var i=0; i < jo.user.length-1; i++ ) {
                    var user = jo.user[i];
                    var option = document.createElement("option");
                    option.text = user.returnedAssociatedData;
                    option.value = option.text;
                    contractScopeHtml.add(option);
                  }
                }
              ).processGet_jo(customerHtmlValue, "contractScope");
            }());
        }
    </script>
```

Tell me if you need more informations.

Thanks in advance

**After Ziganotschka solution:**

gs

```
function processGet_jo(element, returnedAssociatedData) {
  console.log("element: " + element);
  console.log("returnedAssociatedData: " + returnedAssociatedData);
  var uniqueData = [];
  uniqueData.push(getUniqueAssociatedElement(element, returnedAssociatedData));
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  for (var i=0; i < uniqueData.length; i++ ) {
    var record = {};
    record[returnedAssociatedData] = uniqueData[i];
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
  jo.user = dataArray;
  return JSON.stringify(jo);
}

function doGet(element){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("FormFilter").evaluate();
}
```

html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- form -->
    <form id="filterForm" onSubmit="handleFormSubmitFilter(this)">

    <label for="customer"> Customer </label><br/>
    <select id="customer" name="customer" onChange="getcustomerHtmlValue()">
      <option selected></option><br/>
    </select><br/><br/>

      <label for="contractScope"> Contract Scope </label><br/>
      <select name="contractScope" id="contractScope">
        <option selected></option><br/>
      </select><br/><br/>
     
      <label for="acType"> AC Type </label><br/>
      <select multiple id="acType" name="acType">
        <option></option><br/>
      </select><br/><br/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

    <script>
    var customerHtml = document.getElementById("customer");
        var customerHtmlValue = customerHtml.options[customerHtml.selectedIndex].value;
        var contractScopeHtml = document.getElementById("contractScope");
        var contractScopeHtmlValue = contractScopeHtml.options[contractScopeHtml.selectedIndex].value;
        var acTypeHtml = document.getElementById("acType");
        var acTypeHtmlValue = contractScopeHtml.options[contractScopeHtml.selectedIndex].value;
    
    function getcustomerHtmlValue() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function(value) {
            console.log("value: " + value);
            var jo = JSON.parse(value);
            for (var i=0; i < jo.user.length-1; i++) { 
              var user = jo.user[i];
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.text = user.contractScope;
              option.value = option.text;
              contractScopeHtml.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).processGet_jo(customerHtmlValue, "contractScope");
      }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? Hard to reproduce without a full code and / or sample data.

Comment: The problem is in the last .html script function.

The two parameters called with ".processGet_jo(customerHtmlValue, "contractScope"); are not recognized (the previous functions work correctly). There is no error message but nothing happens

Comment: You mean those paramters are not passed correctly from html to code.gs? Did you try to log them?

Comment: I checked with alert, the parameters are good for all the functions except this one.

If I understood, ProcessGet_jo() brings the data which is treated in google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(). But the data doesn't come because the parameters are not recognized

Comment: As far as I can see the variable `returnedAssociatedData` is not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to edit it after some tests. I modified the code

Answer (score 0):

### Your function is being called too early

The syntax `(function () {...}())` will execute the function content directly when the page is loaded.

In your case, you probably would like to select a value from the customer dropdown before passing the selected value to code.gs.

You can do it by e.g. giving the funciton a name and calling it `onChange`.

This test snippet works for me:

*code.gs*

```js
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("html").evaluate();
}
function processGet_jo(element, returnedAssociatedData) {
  console.log("element: " + element)
  console.log("returnedAssociatedData: " + returnedAssociatedData)
  // do something
  return JSON.stringify("success");
}
```

*html.html*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <!-- form -->
        <form id="filterForm" onChange="displayAppropriatedValues(this)" onSubmit="handleFormSubmitFilter(this)">
    
        <label for="customer"> Customer </label><br/>
        <select id="customer" name="customer" onchange="getcustomerHtmlValue()">
          <option selected>1</option><br/>
          <option>2</option><br/>
        </select><br/><br/>   
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>
    
        <script>       
            function getcustomerHtmlValue(){
              var customerHtml = document.getElementById("customer");
              var customerHtmlValue = customerHtml.options[customerHtml.selectedIndex].value;
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
                function(value) {
                console.log("value: " + value);
                // do something
                }
              ).processGet_jo(customerHtmlValue, "contractScope");
           }        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

- Alternatively you can call the function also on form submit instead of on change.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That can be another possibility.

The element value is not detected in my code.
console.log("value: " + value); is empty.
The gs part works. The issue is html-sided.
I edit my code to show you modifications

Comment: If I replace ").processGet_jo(customerHtmlValue, "contractScope");"
by ").processGet_jo("A", "contractScope");"
The element  log works but not the script.

Comment: Hello,
Any ideas to correct the bug ?

Comment: Did you try to log `JSON.stringify(jo)` before returning it from server-side to client-side?

Comment: Yes, it returns "{"user":[{"contractScope":["value1","value2"]}]}"
Value 1 & 2 are the expected values. No issue here